# How to add a new line in tkinter StringVar (\n wot working)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

[image: Have to enter a question]

[image: Want to add \n]

I want to add a new line character.
I take input from Tkinter Entry.
And then [image]
draw it on the image using
PIL library

Comment: From what I know, the ```Text``` widget will be more helpful

Comment: The entry widget can only have a single line.

Answer (score 1):

From the experience I have in `tkinter`, you should go for the `Text` widget.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
text=Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both",expand=1)
button=Button(root,text="Convert to image",command=lambda: print(text.get('1.0','end').strip()))
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```